# Could receiving a URL link, not clicking on it, ever pose a security problem?

Tags: url

Could receiving in a text or an email, a URL link just like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask of a website, which could be a pernicious one, ever pose a security problem at all? What I am asking is that: if I receive such a link but do NOT click on it, will it ever do harm to my account, computer or other website I will ever visit?

---

**Edit**: As a specific example, I would like to ask about the situation for receiving a link, `https://down[.]nnjah68[.]me/app.php/Mjl1to`, in WhatsApp.

Comment: If the link is not shown as plain text, but processed in any way (even just to highlight it), there could be an exploitable bug in the parsing code, such as a buffer overrun. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Some apps generate previews of links. They might send some information to those websites; and the preview image/snippet could contain something you might not want to see.

Comment: Look it another way. Probably the sender's intention is not that complex. Maybe it is just to leverage curiosity of the middle user to **click** on the link and... uhm... redeem that Amazon voucher they just won as the 27182818284th visitor.

Comment: @SalmanA To give an example if an app that does that do that: outlook's default is to show a link preview: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-link-preview-in-outlook-com-and-outlook-on-the-web-ebbfd8ce-d38e-40ef-bb8c-a5362e881163

Comment: @dbkk Adding to what you said about bugs in a URL parser, there could also be bugs in the text rendering engine, e.g. https://www.soyacincau.com/2020/04/24/your-iphone-will-crash-if-it-sees-this-line-of-text/

Comment: There was once a chrome bug where *hovering* over (or clicking) the link `http://a//%%30%30` would cause the tab to crash (see https://superuser.com/questions/977604/what-happens-when-i-hover-over-a-link-in-chrome and e.g. https://9to5google.com/2015/09/22/hovering-over-this-link-will-crash-your-chrome-browser-and-heres-why-video/) - this is an example of a URL-parsing bug, though I don't think it was ever exploitable in any interesting way.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Many browsers send "pings" to any links on a page by performing a DNS query on them to populate the cache. This makes clicking the link faster because the IP is already in the DNS cache. In theory, a bug in this code could be exploitable simply because the link is there. In practice, this isn't an issue. Just because a link exists doesn't mean it can do much to you.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. If the link is received in a WhatsApp message, does that give you any more information to further assess the risk level?

Comment: @Hans I'm not very familiar with WhatsApp, but the risk level for simply _receiving_ a link is incredibly low.

Comment: The particular link I am looking at is https://down.nnjah68.me/app.php/Mjl1. Does this look like a malicious link or site? How do I check if it is a malicious site without actually clicking or going there? Perhaps I should pose this as a separate question?

Comment: @Hans https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/98c1efce0dbb9f4c3de384d1dc8b0290adca742a40ca0e90302a5ed8ebbeaef9/detection (looks harmless, but it's almost certainly spam)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the link in your comment a virus/walware detection/analysis site? Is this a good one?

Comment: @Hans Yes, it is a malware analysis/detection site. It's a popular one. Obviously it does not have a 100% detection rate, however, so use it only with that limitation in mind.

Comment: wait, so my browser is phoning home to every link on every page I visit? The owner of every link I ever see gets a ping when I do?

Comment: @Hans It's used by the Sysinternals suit.

Comment: @benxyzzy: Possibly, yes, depending on browser, version, settings, plugins, add-ons, etc. For priming the DNS cache, a simple DNS lookup would be enough and arguably both more efficient and more privacy-conscious, but OTOH, you'd miss out on redirects that way.

Comment: This seems like a huge privacy issue since any link posted by anyone on a comment section (blog, news, social media or here) would be able to track all visitors. Do you have any source for this or any additional information (which browser are affected, which version, etc.) ?

Comment: @zakinster Although loading the page is possible, most browsers merely do a DNS lookup, so only the nameserver would see what sites you load, not the actual website.

Comment: @forest Do you have any reference for this ? The only documented behaviour I could find is [link prefetching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching) which supports dns-prefetch but it only concerns external resource links (HTML <link> tag for css, js, etc.) not hyperlinks (HTML <a> tag).

Comment: @zakinster Hm, you might be right. I wrote this answer in haste and didn't even think about the fact that it probably doesn't use `HEAD` and just does a DNS lookup. If I can't salvage the answer tomorrow I'll probably delete it. I'm too tired right now to do much about it, though.

Comment: I added a specific example of an app and a link to my question. You may use that example in your answer. I know you already answered regarding the link.

Comment: @benxyzzy No, browsers only query DNS servers of your choice.

Comment: The link being received over WhatsApp (as mentioned in the comment) does change things. WhatsApp will typically try to show you a preview of all links, so it will definitely fetch something from the link and do more than just a ping.

Comment: DNS lookups can also leak information if using a unique, per-user subdomain. Potentially the host could run their own DNS that provides this type of reporting. That said, it can't actually know that it was you who made the request. Gmail automatically fetches images in emails which creates false positives for email marketer's open rates. Neither of these are "security problems" though, just privacy risks.

Answer (score 36):

Some software will automatically fetch any URL it sees, even if you don't click it. A few examples:

- Browsers that are configured to pre-fetch certain URLs so that they load instantly after clicking (this isn't default on any major browser I'm aware of, but I've seen it).
- Messaging clients that show a preview of the page (text and/or image thumbnail) when you send or receive a message with a link.
- Browser extensions that pre-fetch certain links to check the page for malware (part of some AV suites).

In any of these cases, a vulnerability in the HTTP client (browser, AV software, messaging app or server, etc.) could be exploited by an attacker. However, such vulnerabilities are relatively rare unless the client supports JS (it is very hard to make a JS engine fully secure, though of course the developers try) and often sandboxed to limit the damage even if they are vulnerable.

Also, note that - in an ideal world where everything works correctly - fetching a URL would always be safe (it shouldn't be possible for fetching a URL to do anything harmful) and wouldn't even be state-changing (GET *should* be idempotent). Obviously, the real world is not nearly so ideal, since both software vulnerabilities and websites that ignore various standards exist. However, *because* those things exist, and for privacy reasons (fetching a URL always exposes, at a minimum, an IP address), automatically fetching URLs is relatively rare.

Just *looking at* a link (without fetching/visiting it) isn't going to be dangerous unless your text rendering library has some seriously wacky bugs, and most likely they could be set off by non-link text in a situation like that anyhow.

Comment: "vulnerability in the HTTP client" – I believe you mean HTML client there, although of course the HTTP client may *also* have a vulnerability. While HTTP is *much* simpler than HTML and HTTP clients are typically well-tested, we had a rapid evolution recently with the introduction of HTTP/2, HTTP/3, SPDY, and QUIC in rapid succession, which are much younger, less mature, and less well tested than HTTP/1.1. While the server cannot force the client to upgrade to one of those younger protocols, clients do that all by themselves anyway, at least up to HTTP/2.

Comment: No, I definitely meant HTTP. Although many HTTP clients are also HTML clients, the reverse is not necessarily true, see for example libcurl. Fetching a URL is 100% HTTP and 0% HTML, though *rendering* the result of the fetch might (or might not!) involve HTML. After all, an HTTP response can be literally any content type, most of which have nothing to do with HTML (common ones being JSON, various images or videos, any any sort of executable code in binary or script form), or have no content type at all (errors, redirects, 201 responses, etc.).

Comment: If your HTTP client also does something with the response, such as trying to parse / render / execute / etc. it, then of course that's additional attack surface. If it merely writes it to a file or console - as `curl` does by default - then it's possible whatever other software eventually consumes the output will be harmed by it but the problem won't be that you fetched a URL, it's that you fed a malicious input to some program that couldn't handle it. That's a problem, but it's not a "fetch a URL" problem except in the obvious sense that obviously the result of fetching a URL is untrusted.

Comment: Upvote, but the answer would be more awesome with one or two examples of browsers that pre-fetch, messaging clients that preview, and (popular) browser extensions that pre-fetch. Or if anyone else can contribute that information in the comments it could also be handy, purely for knowledge's sake.

Comment: I added a specific example of an app and a link to my question. You may use that example in your answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**
We can be pretty sure this can happen, because something very similar to it did:
https://www.nbcnews.com/tech/security/android-flaw-could-let-hackers-take-over-phone-text-n399016

**Stage-fright**:
There was a bug that got named Stage-fright which was in the image or video-processing on Android.  Because some apps will "view" media automatically to generate a preview, the app automatically runs the media through the buggy library without the need for user intervention.

**Back to your question**:
Currently, many messaging apps, including Discord, generate a preview of links that are sent to you.  If a similar bug were to come back, it would  almost certainly affect people who view the link without opening it, since the app needs to render the link preview.

Comment: Right, but [Stagefright (bug)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_(bug)) as nothing to do with an *URL*!? If *just an example*, I think this could be specified.

Comment: I added a specific example of an app and a link to my question. You may use that example in your answer.

Comment: @Hans In your specific example, almost certainly, no.  I haven't used the app, but it would be considered a security hole.  Even if it did exist, such a bug would probably be patched by now, either by the OS, What'sApp patching it in the app, or blocking such URLs on the What'sApp server.

Answer (score 0):

#### Shortly

- **Yes but**, if you use *confined* tools or smartphone.

  As already metioned in many answer there, *confortable* applications, with previews, pre-download and so on is subjet to software vulnerabilities (in tool himself or in system libraries).

  Of course, this kind of security issues is mostly quickly published and patched.
- **Near no**, if you use text tools in VT console, without picture and preview.

  For sample, I use [mutt](http://mutt.org) mailer, without binding and I manually check attachment when I don't simply ignore them (mostly enterprise logo and other useless tips)

  So if a want to acceed to an url, I have to copy-paste them...(I use `xterm` wich don't offert to automatically open browser by clicking on URL)

Comment: I added a specific example of an app and a link to my question. You may use that example in your answer.